# Android Things hardwareAccelerated="true" makes app slow on Raspberrypi 3

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, android-things

Why the app becomes **so slow** when hardware acceleration is activated by placing

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

on the Android manifest?

What can I do to avoid it but still use hardware acceleration ?

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Which OS version of Android Things are you using? If it isn't the latest version, try that and report back on behavior.

Comment: Hi, I'm using 1.0.2. Guess it is the latest. Is it ?

Comment: That's is what I'm seeing. Unfortunately I don't have RaspPi3 so I can't check, so hopefully someone else can chime in. One suggestion is that if you have a older build that you can flash to check if the hardwareAccelerated for RPi regressed (assuming same physical configuration). Also you should describe what your app is doing in case that is the cause.